# Improve my "Crossfit" regime?

Tags: running, diet, workout-routines, weights, crossfit

## All Day Workout

I have time to play with, and I think I've been a bit random with my workouts. I want all round fitness, and I'd say I'm fairly intermediate. Do you think there's anything I can add or shuffle round in my routine?

### My Stats

Physique:

- Weight: 12 stone/75 kg
- Height: 5 foot 10
- Age: 19

Weights:

- Dumbbell curls: 17.5kg (4 reps)
- Dumbell lateral raise: 10kg (6 reps)
- Bench-Press: 25kg (4 reps)
- Dead-lift: 35kg (16 reps)
- Grip Strengthener: 18kg resistance (20 reps)
- Kettlebell: 18kg

Running:

- Half marathon(13 miles): 1:40

### Routine

Everyday:

- 1 hour morning swim (irregular)
- 5 mile run/walk (sometimes again after lunch)
- Kettlebell/Dumbbell/Grip Strengthener/Ab Exercises through the day

Evenings:

- Monday - hour of gymnastics
- Tuesday/Friday - 3 hours of Dead-lifting, Bench-pressing and Climbing
- Wednesday/Thursday - hour of swimming
- Saturday/Sunday- feck all

### Diet

Light breakfast/dinner (veg, fruit, wheat and oats) and a heavy lunch (protein). No junk/dessert/drinking.

### Problems

- I struggle to keep a steady pace on my own. Yet, I ran a half-marathon in 1:40 with this kind of fools training.
- Waking up to swim at 7. My diet's helped but it's not golden, and I avoid alarm clocks.
- Stuck in a rut with weights. I expected my dead-lifting to suffer (went from 5 times a week to twice if that), but the dumbbells I use everyday aren't getting much easier.
- What's the best way to work martial arts into this?

Comment: How much weights do you have? What does "gymnastics" consist of?

Comment: 1 adjustable 30kg dumbbell, 1 adjustable 15 kg dumbbell, 1 18kg kettlebell. Gymnastics consists of flips, pullups, and stuff using all the equipment [you see here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gymnastics+equipment&safe=active&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDIQsARqFQoTCIbM65Xl2sYCFfQX2wodwM8EvQ)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is general fitness then you're doing plenty of running, walking, and swimming, but your deadlift is quite light. Sixteen reps is also a lot for the deadlift. If it's possible to use more weight but fewer reps per set, do that. 60kg to 100kg should be entirely doable for you within a few months.

Other ways to get good use out of your limited weights are Turkish get-ups, overhead presses, and kettlebell swings and snatches. The swings are a good alternative if you don't have the equipment to deadlift heavy.